# Equivalence of operations by a function of certain sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Show that if $f : A \to B$ and $G,H$ are subsets of $B$, then $f^{-1}(G \cup H) = f^{-1}(G) \cup f^{-1} (H)$ and also that $f^{-1}(G \cap H) = f^{-1}(G) \cap f^{-1}(H)$.

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $ x \in f^{-1}(G \cup H) $. This occurs if and only if

$$f(x) \in G \cup H \iff f(x) \in G  \; or \; f(x) \in H \iff x \in f^{-1}(G) \; or \; f^{-1}(H) $$

$$ \iff x \in f^{-1}(G) \cup f^{-1}(H) $$

Similarly, Suppose $ x \in f^{-1}(G \cap H) $. This occurs if and only if

$$f(x) \in G \cap H \iff f(x) \in G  \; and \; f(x) \in H \iff x \in f^{-1}(G) \; and \; f^{-1}(H) $$

$$ \iff x \in f^{-1}(G) \cap f^{-1}(H) $$

The result then follows by the following definition :

For any sets $A, B$: $$A = B \iff A \subseteq B \; \; and \; \; B \subseteq A $$

which is the same as $$ x \in A \iff x \in B $$

Comment: Rather simple I suppose, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? You're familiar with the definition of the preimage of a map?

**Hint**: Take an element $a \in f^{-1}(G \cup H)$ and try to show, that it is already in $f^{-1}(G) \cup f^{-1}(H)$, and conversely.